# Google Cloud Multiple Static IP Addresses

Tags: cloud, vpn, vpc

I am developing a platform which requires a VPN with a static IP, which will be routing data to a VPC.
I would also like to have this VPC with a static external IP address, where I could develop my backend and frontend service.
So, I end up with a VPC Network, with a VPN(Static external IP) with a static internal IP, that sends data to a VPC on a static internal IP. Then, I want my VPC to be exposed with a static external IP. But I am limited to one per zone.
Is there a solution for this? Am I looking at this the wrong way?
Pic:
[image]

Comment: From the diagram I think you're trying to use a VPS and a VPC but the question seemingly talks about 2 VPCs (one with a vpn gateway and one for development with a static ip) and no VPS at all. Please clarify :-)

Comment: Also, are you on a free trial account - the one that gives you $300 for a year? There is a restriction of 1 static external IP per zone on those accounts. If so, you'll have to enable billing and pay for the extra addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In real world, only frontend is exposed. Exposed backend only brings risks. Think how dangerous that your MySQL server can be accessed by anyone.

During development stage, you can

- Have everything installed on the single VM
- Exposed it with an external IP on an isolated virtual network
- For all the backend services that does not need to be accessed externally, make them listen to 127.0.0.1, or the internal virtual network addresses.

Comment: That is exactly what i ended up doing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address), Google allows `one static IP per resource`. There is no way to get around this.